# SFK to convert text to sound with minimodem?

Tags: audio, conversion, modem, telephony

I've installed minimodem on a server running Ubuntu. I've read through the [documentation](http://www.whence.com/minimodem/minimodem.1.html) but still having trouble. I want to input a text file and use [frequency shift keying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying#Audio_FSK) to output an audio file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive answer to this question is:

```
cat example.txt | minimodem --write 1200 -f converted-example.wav
```

After the generation, you may check with this command

```
minimodem --read 1200 -f converted-example.wav > regenerated.txt && diff example.txt regenerated.txt
```

For further usage, check the man page again.